# ¿Cómo aumentar el valor de un registro en una ruta en Django?

Tags: django

Quisiera saber si me pueden guiar para lograr por medio de un botón, incrementar el valor de un registro al próximo, por ejemplo:

> De http://127.0.0.1:8000/paciente/1/detalle pasar al siguiente
> http://127.0.0.1:8000/paciente/2/detalle

Comment: No olvides mostrar qué has intentado hasta el momento. Lee [ask].